# C++ Visual Studio 2012 Getting Box2D and SFML to work together

Tags: c++, box2d, linker-errors, sfml

Basically I'm trying to get SFML and Box2D to work together under VS2012.
I've got both of them to work independently, however I can't get them to work together.

If I try run them together I get a bunch of:

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in Main.obj
```

If I change the RuntimeLibrary value in the properties from MDd to MTd I then get a bunch of errors such as:

```
error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)
error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)
error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)
```

a bunch of those along with two warnings:

```
 warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library` 
 warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'libcmtd.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Which if I do also doesn't work and i get a bunch of errors similar to:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __purecall`

For SFML I'm absolutely positive that I built it right. For Box2D on the other hand I'm not so sure. I used [this guide](http://aneelkkhatri.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/setting-up-box2d-library-in-visual-studio-c/) and as you can see it's for VS2010. However I got no errors while building and HelloWorld.cpp example ran without any problems.

So is there anything I can do to make this work?

**EDIT:** I've gotten it to work, however only for debug version
What I did was I tried rebuilding the Box2D library as /MTd for debug and /MT for release
The debug one built fine while the Release version did not.
Debug version works fine, however release version throws

```
warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

and errors almost identical to the second list of errors in this post

Any solutions to this?

**EDIT_2:** It seems that the issue was in the dll files. I rebuilt SFML and now it seems to be working. I'll do some more tests later to determine if i had fixed it or not.

Comment: Have you tried the advice on the last error: `use /NODEFAULTLIB:library` ?

Comment: @tehinternetsismadeofcatz yes I have and it threw a bunch of errors as well. I've done some more tests and it seems that it's in fact SFML's fault. I created a fresh project to test the libraries and SFML will build but when I try to run it in Debug or Release I get `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application` error. Something weird is going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I fixed it and here is how.

First things first. If you get a bunch of linker errors then you've probably messed something up while linking the library. Check your linker settings in your IDE.

What I messed up was, I was changing the Runtime Library values in Project properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation settings in Visual Studio 2012(for some unknown reason). Which caused the numerous linker errors.

After I finally fixed those my application compiled succesfully, however upon trying to run it I got:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application
```

What this turned out to be is faulty .dll files it seems. I've rebuilt the latest SFML2 using CMake and then rebuilt the libs and dlls in VS2012, and now everything works.

I'm still not sure what caused them to stop working properly in the first place since I used these same .dll files before and they all of a sudden started throwing me that error.

From what I could gather `(0xc000007b)` could be linked to:

> The problem was due to 32/64-bit mismatches of various system dlls required by Visual studio. Somehow the dlls it needs got replaced by 64-bit versions that it couldn’t load.

Source: [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96035692-9a50-40d4-a7d3-48bda87d11ec/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b-click-ok-to-close-the-application-when)

So that might've been my issue.

So what did I learn from this:

1. Don't fiddle with things you don't fully understand
2. If you get any errors while building, don't just skim through them, read them all, because almost always there will be some useful info regarding your issue
3. If you decide to build the libraries yourself, or have no other option but to build them yourself, then make sure to follow the instructions properly(granted if there are any) and always run individual tests before trying to link multiple libraries together otherwise you're going to blame the wrong library for your faults